# Двумерный массив объектов spring, jpa, postgres

Tags: java, массивы, postgresql, jpa, spring-jpa

Нужно занести в базу данных двумерный массив объектов, фрагмент кода:

```
public class Event {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 30)
    private String nameevent;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 400)
    private String address;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    @DateTimeFormat
    private Calendar datetime;

    @????
    private  Seat[][] arraySeat;
```

Класс Seat:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seats")
public class Seat {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private int x;

    private int y;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Guest guest;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20)
    private TypeSeats type;

}
```

IDE выдает ошибку `'Basic' attribute type should not be 'Seat[][]'`, ругается на:

```
private  Seat[][] arraySeat;
```

в классе Event.

Если использовать аннотацию `@ElementCollection`, то ошибка :`'Element Collection' attribute type should not be array.`
Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Аннотация @Type в помощь. Ссылка на пример https://vladmihalcea.com/multidimensional-array-jpa-hibernate. Но вообще по хорошему такого избегать, и пересмотреть модель сущности.

Comment: @Charismatic, Спасибо, но это не совсем то что мне нужно, в примере массив заполняется по сути string элементами.
а мне бы хотелось иметь вид :
"array": [
[{id = 1, name = "qwe"}, {id = 2, name = "qwe"}],
[{id = 3, name = "qwe"}, {id = 4, name = "qwe"}],
[{id = 5, name = "qwe"}, {id = 6, name = "qwe"}],
],

Comment: По какому критерию БД должна понимать, что объект Seat относится к первому или второму массиву (из примера в комментарии) ? У Seat указана связь вида `@OneToOne`, с другой стороны аналогичная связь будет?

Comment: @MrFylypenko, Спасибо за ответ,  БД будет принимать данные из JSON, который будет приходить с фронта(соответственно ему понимать не надо что куда относится).
У Seat  связь вида `@OneToOne` с другой стороны будет аналогичная связь.